# Exceptions handling trouble

Tags: exception

Trying to add divide by zero exception in my calculator project through the try/catch block:

```
private class Calculate implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                if (operation.equals("/")) {
                    display.setText(Double.toString(getResult() / Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
                    setResult(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
                }
                else if (operation.equals("*")) {
                        display.setText(Double.toString(getResult() * Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
                        setResult(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
                }
                else if (operation.equals("-")) {
                    display.setText(Double.toString(getResult() - Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
                        setResult(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
                }
                else if (operation.equals("+")) {
                        display.setText(Double.toString(getResult() + Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
                        setResult(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
                }
                if (display.getText().endsWith(".0")) {
                    display.setText(display.getText().replace(".0", ""));
                }
                calculationMade = true;
                operation = "";
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
                display.setText("You cannot divide by zero!");
            }
        }
    }
```

But in this way it still writes me "Infinity" in a text field. Can anybody suggest where i'm wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

When working with `double`, zero division returns `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` (depending on operand signs)

```
System.out.println(1.0d/0d);
System.out.println(-1.0d/0d);
System.out.println(1.0d/-0d);
System.out.println(-1.0d/-0d);
```

Only non-decimal arithmetic throws an exception on zero division. And the exception is not an `IllegalArgumentException` but an `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how can i fix my problem nonetheless? I changed exception to Arithmetic, but obviously still have the same result.

Comment: Check for zero value before doing division and removes your `try catch`

Comment: Well, that's helped a lot, thank you for your time:)